# Using Properties String in Spring XML configuration file

Tags: java, spring, properties

Is there a way to set a property of a bean in a Spring configuration file to that of a string read from a Properties file?

e.g.

```
<bean id="...." class="....">
    <property name="loginURL">GET_THIS_VALUE_FROM_'ENV.PROPERTIES'_FILE</property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use a [PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) to load a properties file, and then refer to the properties using an Spring-EL expression -

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:custom.properties"/>

<bean id="...." class="....">
    <property name="loginURL">${propname}</property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, each server picked up its own property file whose name came from the system variable.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" value="classpath:/config/#{systemProperties['APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_FILE']}"/>
    </bean>
```

After this, I had to add the property key via Spring JSTL expression e.g

```
class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter">
        <property name="signingKey" value="${oauth.signingkey}"/>
        <property name="jwtClaimsSetVerifier" ref="OauthClaimVerifier"/>
    </bean>
```